# Tomcat 5.5 DBCP Connection Pool DataSource is closed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm developing a Spring web app with Spring Data JPA and Hibernate, running on Tomcat 5.5. The Tomcat uses DBCP for connection pooling.

The pool is defined like this:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory"
        logAbandoned="true" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
        minIdle="3" name="..." password="..." removeAbandoned="true"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        url="..." username="..." validationQuery="select 1" />
```

On the Java side I get the Datasource via JNDI and Spring manages the object as a singelton and it will only be used to create the 
EntityManagerFactory.

Now my problem. When I first deploy the app on the freshly started Tomcat everything works fine. If I hot-deploy the app for the first time everything still works fine. But then if I hot-deploy for a second time I get following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1362)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
```

Any idea is appreciated, thanks!

**Update:** I tried it with Tomcat 7.0.12, which was lying around on my machine and had the same problem. I've than switched from commons-dbcp to Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool and the problem was gone on both Tomcat 5.5 and Tomcat 7. It now seems to me that there is a bug in commons-dbcp or Spring doesn't play nice with it? Does somebody know more about this?

Comment: Tomcat 5.5? Are you sure? The Apache website lists 6, 7 and 8. How old is your server? For Java 1.4, Servlet 2.4 and JSP 2.0? Really?

Comment: Hi Elliott, yes I'm sure update process is a bit slow here ... :-) We are already on Java 1.6 though!

Comment: Check the requirements for spring and hibernate versions your using. That Tomcat is *really old*. And maybe switch to a different CP.

Comment: We've had a lot of issues with this as well.  UCP seems to be the only connection pool that properly validates oracle connections :(

Comment: So I guess I'll have to live with this situation until we upgrade. Shouldn't be so long anymore, I hope. Thanks guys.

Comment: Had some new findings and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a supported Tomcat version. Commons DBCP is dead/outdated. You should use Tomca JDBC Pool or Commons DBCP2.

Answer (score 0):

Define an empty destroyMethod for datasource Spring bean. On undeploy Spring calls `close()` or `shutdown()` on beans if no destroyMethod is defined.
See this [Why does Datasources close on Tomcat 7 undeploy with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149969/why-does-datasources-close-on-tomcat-7-undeploy-with-spring-boot).

In `data.xml`

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" destroy-method="">
```

or in `@Bean` annotation

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "")
public DataSource getDataSource() {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

In new versions of Tomcat, datasources implement AutoClosable. By default, Spring detects that interface and on undeployment, invokes close on the datasource. In some versions of bugged Spring (4.1.x and <4.2.2) if AutoClosable interface is detected, destroyMethod is ignored.

Another way to avoid this fact is to wrap the datasource.

```
    @Bean
public DataSource getJndiDataSource() {
    try {
        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) jndiTemplate.lookup("java:comp/env/"+JNDI_DATASOURCE);
        return new DelegatingDataSource(ds);
    } catch(NamingException e){
        LOG.error("Could not find JNDI data source (java:comp/env/):"+JNDI_DATASOURCE, e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

By wrapping the Datasource with DelegatingDataSource, the AutoClosable interface is not exposed to the context and thus, the Datasource is not closed.