# Why does Datasources close on Tomcat 7 undeploy with Spring Boot

Tags: tomcat7, spring-boot

I have an application that has a datasource.  Everytime I undeploy the application from the manager GUI the datasources are being closed.  When I try to redeploy, the datasource stays closed and throws the following exception:

```
{
  "status" : "DOWN",
  "error" : "org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed"
}

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1362) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044) ~[tomcat-dbcp.jar:7.0.53]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.1.Final.jar:4.3.1.Final]
    ... 81 common frames omitted
```

Restarting the server solves this issue but that is not an acceptable solution for a production application.

I have a different application with a different datasource with the same issue.

Both application are using Spring Boot version 1.1.4 with Tomcat 7.  One of the applications was converted to Spring Boot and didn't have the datasource issues before conversion.

Below is how I create the Datasource currently in my Spring Boot Application.java file.

```
@Bean()
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("com.datasource.CONSUMER");
    }
```

How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: I don't think Spring is going to just close your `DataSource` without you telling it to do so. So something must be missing. Another bean definition with the same ID maybe (you would see a warning on startup)?

Comment: I'm not seeing any warnings.

Comment: That was just a guess, but there still isn't enough information to get to the bottom of it. Can you spike your server with a `BasicDataSource` that throws an exception when it is closed? That would tell you where the close call is coming from.

Comment: How do I spike the server with a BasicDataSource?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This isn't specific to Spring Boot, it's standard Spring behaviour.

By default, Spring will infer a bean's destroy method. From the [javadoc for `@Bean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#destroyMethod--):

> As a convenience to the user, the container will attempt to infer a destroy method against an object returned from the `@Bean` method. For example, given an `@Bean` method returning an Apache Commons DBCP `BasicDataSource`, the container will notice the `close()` method available on that object and automatically register it as the `destroyMethod`. This 'destroy method inference' is currently limited to detecting only public, no-arg methods named 'close' or 'shutdown'.

The javadoc goes on to describe how to disable this behaviour:

> To disable destroy method inference for a particular `@Bean`, specify an empty string as the value, e.g. `@Bean(destroyMethod="")`

You need to update your `dataSource()` method:

```java
@Bean(destroyMethod="")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("com.datasource.CONSUMER");
}
```

Comment: I recently ran into this issue when switching from a tcserver instance (configured to use Tomcat 8) to a stand alone installation of Tomcat 8.  Any ideas as to why that would make a difference. I'm stumped.