# Connection closes using JNDI in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jndi

Running under a Tomcat 9 and JDK 1.8, using Spring 5, I am trying to configure a JNDI connection to get a DataSource.

If I configure Spring, through XML, I get my DataSource and everything seems to work fine. I configured the DataSource in my applicationContext.xml, in this way:

```
<jee: jndi-lookup id = "dataSource" jndi-name = "jdbc / yages"
        resource-ref = "true" />
```

When I use the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer class to initialize Spring, my DataSource is created but when I try to catch the connection it gives me the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed
>       at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource (BasicDataSource.java:2049)

I try to create the DataSource with this function:

```
@Bean (name = "dataSource")
  public DataSource dataSource (Environment env) throws NamingException
  {
        DataSource datasource = null;
        try {
            JndiDataSourceLookup lookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup ();
            datasource = lookup.getDataSource ("jdbc/yages");
            datasource.getConnection ();               
            return datasource;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace ();
        }
        return datasource;
  }
```

It seems that the DataSource is created correctly, but the connection to the database seems to be closed.
However, if I use the DataSource, configure it through XML, it works well for me, which is why I assume that it is not a problem neither of the connection to the database nor of the configuration of Tomcat.

Any idea why the connection is closed?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you call getConnection() on the datasource? Also have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149969/why-does-datasources-close-on-tomcat-7-undeploy-with-spring-boot

Comment: I don't see anywhere in what you provide that this has anything to do with opening a connection, the error is specifically about the datasource being closed. Which might be an indication it was never successfully opened to begin with. That jndi name in the configuration looks very strange, is it really with spaces in it?

Comment: I call to getConnection, only for test. If the connection is closed then Java throws an Exception.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
It is to create the Bean with this instruction

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource", destroyMethod = "")
```

The problem is that Spring to do an undeploy, destroy the Bean and close the connection. To avoid this, I have to change the default behavior of Spring.