# Failed to obtain JDBC Connection. java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed

Tags: java, jdbc, jndi

This is first time I am working with Spring boot & Tomcat 8. I face issue after deployment on Tomcat server, I am not able to get instance of JNDI datasource.

In log file, I see error

> Error retrieving database meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Data source is closed

Below are code from server.xml and Context.xml

```html
*** Server.xml ***
<Resource name="jdbc/jndiDs" global="jdbc/jndiDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" url="connection url" username="username" password="password" /> 

***Context.xml ***
<ResourceLink name="jdbc/jndiDs" global="jdbc/jndiDs" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

However, when I use DriverManagerDataSource as bean in my configuration class, it works without any issue.

Below is the java code used to insert data using stored procedure

```
 SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("COP00166_001_1.Capture")
                    .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess();
            call.declareParameters(new SqlParameter("sPMsgTx", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("sPConLegacyId", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("nPConId", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("nPPceNr", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("nPBulCsysIdCorig", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("nPBulCsysIdOrig", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("nPBulCsysIdDest", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("nPBulCsysIdOcc", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("dPPcsEventLt", OracleTypes.TIMESTAMP),
                    new SqlParameter("sPMsgBarcodeTypCd", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("sPMsgBarcodeValTx", Types.VARCHAR), 
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("sPMsgTx", ConsignmentMatchingHelper.linearizeXml(msg));
        map.put("sPConLegacyId", shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getConLegacyNr().trim());
        map.put("nPConId", null);
        map.put("nPPceNr",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getPieceNr() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getPieceNr().trim()
                        : null);
        map.put("nPBulCsysIdCorig",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsEntryBL() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsEntryBL().trim()
                        : null);
        map.put("nPBulCsysIdOrig", null);
        map.put("nPBulCsysIdDest",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsRecBL() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsRecBL().trim()
                        : null);
        map.put("nPBulCsysIdOcc",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsEventBL() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getCsEventBL().trim()
                        : null);
        map.put("dPPcsEventLt", ConsignmentMatchingHelper
                .covertToTimestamp(shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getEventDate().getLocal()));
        map.put("sPMsgBarcodeTypCd",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getBarCdType() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getBarCdType().trim()
                        : null);
        map.put("sPMsgBarcodeValTx",
                (shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getBarCdValue() != null)
                        ? shipmentMatch.getShipmentDetail().getBarCdValue().trim()
                        : null);
    call.execute(map);
```

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException is when execute method is called.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Datasources close on Tomcat 7 undeploy with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25149969/why-does-datasources-close-on-tomcat-7-undeploy-with-spring-boot)

Comment: I have already tried solution given in the link mentioned by @KarolDowbecki before asking this question and still the issue persists. I am actually using SimpleJdbccall provided by spring to call stored procedure for inserting data.While calling stored procedure I am neglecting the procedure meta data and creating my own custom metadata and getting an exception as mentioned in question.Thanks

Comment: please update the question to reflect this

Comment: @KarolDowbecki I have updated the question.Could you please look into this once know your views?